# Handle multiple upload buttons using same function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am working on multiple file upload for different categories. for eg. one upload button for images, next button for documents. I am using 2 same functions but different name to make it work independently. But i would like to know if same functions can work for as many upload buttons, since both the function's functionalities are exactly the same but just a different name.

This is html file

```
<input (onUpload)="multipleUpload1($event)" multiple="true" type="file" />

<input (onUpload)="multipleUpload2($event)" multiple="true" type="file" />
```

I have `multipleUpload1` and `multipleUpload2` but has same code but just 2 different names. If I use this way, I get exactly what I wanted but please let know if there is any other way so that I can write only once and work for as many upload buttons as I need.

`multipleUpload1` and `multipleUpload2` are functions where I have logic to upload files and it works fine.

I am using ng2-uploader plugin for handling file upload.

Below is my TS code

```
private responses: any[] = [];

multipleUpload1(data: any): void{
 let index = this.responses.findIndex(x => x.id === data.id);

  if(index === -1) {
    this.responses.push(data);
  }
  else {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.responses[index] = data;
    });
  }
}

multipleUpload2(data: any): void{
 let index = this.responses.findIndex(x => x.id === data.id);

  if(index === -1) {
    this.responses.push(data);
  }
  else {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.responses[index] = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the same function on both inputs?

Comment: @Robba if i use same function on both then on uploading file from one upload button, it gets uploaded on another as well

Comment: What do you mean by 'gets uploaded on another as well'? The file gets uploaded twice?

Comment: @Robba yes it gets uploaded twice

Comment: That's very odd, looks a bit like a bug in ng2-uploader. Looking at their docs I do see they add an ngFileSelect attribute to their input which seems to be missing from yours. Could that be related?

Comment: @Robba yes i do have that ngFileSelect thing as well in my real code and it works perfectly if i use the functions with different function's name with exactly same code, only the thing i want to implement is using the same function for both the upload buttons so that i don't have to rewrite the functions for all the buttons

Comment: My guess is that it's a bug in the ng2-uploader. You could check out their code and see if you can find out what's going on. There has to be some way the uploaders determine that a file was selected that somehow gets mixed up.

Comment: @Robba can you give me some basic idea of using single function by multiple upload buttons.... i hope you understand what i mean... thanks

Comment: I thing if you'd rename one of the functions to simply `multipleUpload` and remove the other, and update the html template to use the same name in both places it should work. If it doesn't there's probably something wrong with ng2-uploader and you'd have to debug that code or take it up with its creator.

Comment: @Robba this is what i did and as i said before it gets uploaded twice... anyways thanks for your effort and willingness to help

Comment: I'm curious now though, maybe I'll have some time tonight to look into ng2-uploader and see if I can find a reason...